# My 3rd level domain isn't working properly via nginx being a reverse proxy

Tags: linux, nginx, domain-name-system, ssl

A part of an nginx config for my website "staging.my_website.com"
Nginx is a reverse proxy in this case:

```
  server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      server_name staging.my_website.com;
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name localhost www.staging.my_website.com;
    return 301 https://staging.my_website.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
      listen 443 ssl default_server;
      listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
      server_name staging.my_website.com;

      location / {
        # ...............

        proxy_pass          http://localhost:1234;
        proxy_redirect      http://localhost:1234 https://staging.my_website.com;
```

It doesn't work:

```
staging.my_website.com show the default page of nginx
htttps://staging.my_website.com -- unavailable
```

Also:

```
  $ curl -v http://localhost:1234

  * Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:1234/
  *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
  * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 1234 (#0)
  > GET / HTTP/1.1
  > Host: localhost:1234
  > User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
  > Accept: */*
  > 
  < HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  < server: ......
  < date: .............
  < content-length: 0
  < cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
  < location: https://my_website.com/           # why not staging?????
  < 
  * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Note that on "my_website.com" - a separate server - all is working well.

**update**:

I've redeployed my web app. However, all remains the same. Except this:

```
  # .............
  < location: https://staging.my_website.com/
```

But as before:

```
staging.my_website.com -- shows the default page of nginx

htttps://staging.my_website.com -- unavailable
```

Comment: According to your curl output the problem isn't nginx, but whatever  you are running on port 1234.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, no.

Comment: When you access your application server directly it answers with a redirect. This clearly is an issue with your application server.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, hmmmmm,

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, actually not,see my update

Comment: `unavailable` is not a helpful error message. Please post the actual return code and error message you get when you access `https://staging.my_website.com`.

Comment: It could be that you are just missing a `/` at the end of your `proxy_pass`. That would result in nginx trying to proxy `/whatever.html` to `http://localhost:1234whatever.html`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, yes, but on my main website it's also missing and it's working

Comment: error -- port 443 connection refused

Comment: Test the configuration using `nginx -T`. Should `staging` be the default server?

Comment: @RichardSmith, it's ok. I had to remove /sites-available/default even though it wasn't copied into "...enabled". Whereas my "staging" config was in both directories. Do you know why I had to remove "default"?